# How to get the name from a user id

Tags: jquery, user, xml, ajax

I query a list via jQuery (on the RSS presentation). The content type has one field that is used for a responsible. In the XML returned, only the User ID is supplied.

How can I get the name of that user in my jQuery code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use CAML to query for your data?

Then use this query

```
<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name=\"User\" LookupId=\"TRUE\" /><Value Type=\"User\">{0}</Value></Eq></Where>
```

to query the list "User Information List" for the user with the ID {0}

Comment: Currently, no. I just query the List `_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyList` and iterate over the results... and one of them is the UserId for which I'd like to have the name. I need to keep it as simple as possible, so I'm not sure If i can incorporate this query language

Comment: Okay you make your live harder than it should be. Two recommendations for you:
a) use http://spservices.codeplex.com/ to do the query stuff
b) Query /_vti_bin/ListData.svc/UserInformationList to get all users - then do the matching.

Comment: I don't find this especially hard... traversing XML with jQuery is actually quite easy. Thanks for the userinformationlist SVC, this is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: I said harder than it should be :) SPServices is mature and used by many others in production environments. Do you cover all edge cases? 
I am not trying to convince you - use whatever works for you ;)

Comment: I will definitely use that as soon as I get this in production - currently, it is only a showcase which needs to be implemented with as low effort as possible, which for me, is easier achieved by using XML/jQuery because I already know these technologies, in contrast to learning a "new" one. But, for the actual project, I will use something more elaborate and safe :) Thanks for the links!